# How to solve Markov chain hitting probabilities with linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains

Suppose that we are given a Markov chain with three states (not necessarily irreducible) and we want to calculate the hitting probabilities for various states, say for state 1. Is it possible to solve the equations from the original $3 \times 3$ transition matrix $P$ and probability vector $a$, where $a_1 = 1, a_i = \sum_{j \in S}P(i, j)a(i), i = 2, 3$? I know that it is possible to reduce the matrix by eliminating rows corresponding to our states of interest; any constants that are caused by our states of interest can be formed by summing the columns corresponding to our states of interest, and then eliminating those columns. In our case, we would eliminate row 1 and by denoting the reduced column by $c$, our equation would be $\bar{P} \bar{a} + c = \bar{a}$, where $\bar{P}$ is the corresponding $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: I don't understand your notation.  What is $a_i$ and what is $a(i)$?  More generally, can you give a numerical example and show what you mean by the various row and column elimination?

Comment: @antkam As much as I would like to, the whole process just clicked for me the other day. Therefore I do not really have a need for an answer. In any case, thanks for giving this question a thought!

Comment: @Qwaster If you have an answer, then you can answer the question. You cannot award yourself the bounty, but this is a priority question so you should answer it if you get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea occurred to me the other day, so I'll finish this thread by giving a high level description. When solving some system of equations involving Markov chain where for a function $g$, $g(x) = c(x) + \sum_{y \in S}P(x,y)g(y): x \notin A$ and $g(x) = 0, x \in A$, given a transition matrix P the task is really to solve the vector $g$ from the following equation: $Pg + C = g$, where $C$ denotes any constants that are to be added in the system. As the chain might not be able to access some states and depending on the exact configuration some values of $g$ might be computable from the get-go, such states are to be evaluated and the end result will be a linear system involving only a portion of the original components and column vectors.

Comment: +1 ,thanks. While it may feel that this "portion" of the original components and vectors is not relatable to the original matrix in any manner, a consolation is that at least it is of smaller computational size. Furthermore, if your matrix is already in a standard form (i.e the transition matrix has rows/columns sorted in order of recurrent and transient states) then getting this portion is easier, I would think.